# How to make a List comprehension for reversed words?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing some code on list comprehensions , what the program needs do is print any palindrome that's at least 5 characters long(which I already have done) from the standard input and also reversed. For example "Damon" "nomad" "revel" "lever" should all be put in to the one list with the palindrome words.

Ive tried stackoverflow and other programming websites for help , the task has been completed correctly but not in list comprehension form.

```
import sys
line = sys.stdin
all_text = [a.strip() for a in line]
atleast_5_letters = [a for a in all_text if len(a) >= 5]
reverse_words = [a for a in atleast_5_letters]
palindrome = [a for a in atleast_5_letters if a[::-1].upper() == a.upper()]
print(palindrome)

#stdin input:
#Ababa
#aaaaa
#bob
#civic
#ccccc
#Damon
#england
#Hannah
#lager
#leper
#level
#lever
#madam
#minim
#nomad
#radar
#racecar
#RaCeCar
#refer
#regal
#repel
#revel
#rever
#rotor
#tenet
#queen
```

['Ababa', 'civic', 'Damon', 'Hannah', 'lager', 'leper', 'level', 'lever', 'madam', 'minim', 'nomad', 'radar', 'refer', 'regal', 'repel', 'revel', 'rever', 'rotor', 'tenet']

Comment: Well, the same thing you're doing for the palindrome.. but do it for one of them :)

Comment: Could you elaborate ? Im not sure how to do that in python

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I'd get a lowercase set of your five letter words (this makes the next step easier):

```
atleast_5_letters_lower = set([w.lower() for w in atleast_5_letters])
```

Then, find words from a list where that word also appears as a reversal in the set, ignoring capitalisation, but keeping the original capitalisation:

```
reverse_words = [a for a in atleast_5_letters if a[::-1].lower() in atleast_5_letters_lower]
```

Result with your input words:

```
['Ababa', 'aaaaa', 'bob', 'civic', 'ccccc', 'Damon', 'Hannah', 'lager', 'leper', 'level', 'lever', 'madam', 'minim', 'nomad', 'radar', 'racecar', 'RaCeCar', 'refer', 'regal', 'repel', 'revel', 'rever', 'rotor', 'tenet']
```

Comment: Better make `atleast_5_letters_lower` a `set`; otherwise fine.

Comment: It works fine without set , whats the idea of using set ?

Comment: Oh sorry you need the set , but why ?

Comment: `sets` are implemented as hash tables (like dictionaries), so looking up whether an element exists in a `set` is generally faster than with a list.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this what you are looking for

```
palindrome=[a for a in all_text if (len(a) >= 5 and a[::-1].upper()==a.upper())]
```

Saving palindrome with length greater than 5.

Answer (score 0):

Another method using single list comprehension:

```
import sys
line = sys.stdin
print ([a.strip() for a in line if len(a.strip()) >= 5 if a.strip()[::-1].upper() == a.strip().upper()])
```

**Note:** This will print only Palindrome words which are greater than 5 letters, not reversed words for Non-Palindromes.

---

**Sample Input:**

```
Ababa
aaaaa
bob
civic
Damon
```

**Sample Output:**

```
['Ababa', 'aaaaa', 'civic']
```

Answer (score 0):

For readability sake, `reversed()` is great for palindrome check.

```
line = """#Ababa
#aaaaa
#bob
#civic
#ccccc
#Damon
"""

#line = line.splitlines()
all_text = [a.strip('#') for a in line.splitlines() if len(a) >= 5] 
palindrome = [a for a in all_text if ("".join(reversed(a.lower())) == a.lower())]
print(palindrome, end=' ')
#Output:
['Ababa', 'aaaaa', 'civic', 'ccccc']
```